# How to get the value(only) of an attribute using xpath?

Tags: html, xpath

I have a question about using XPath to get the value of an attribute. I know that using `@` can get the attributename-value pair, but what if I only want to get the value?

Let me give you an example:
Fr this link: http://www.campbellskitchen.com/?pd=yes&sekw=10941064280

If I use Chrome and use `$x("//a[contains(.,'BRAND')]/following-sibling::div//a/@title")`

It will return me an array of something like this:

`[title="Campbell's Condensed soup", title="Campbell's Gravies", title="Swanson Broth and Stock" ...]`

This is NOT what I want, I want the return array to be:

`[Campbell's Condensed soup, Campbell's Gravies, Swanson Broth and Stock ...]`

```
<li role="menuitem" class="parent"><a href="/Brands?fm=link_navigated" title="BRANDS"
                role="link" tabindex="10" accesskey="b">
                BRANDS</a>
                <div class="subnavi dropdown_5columns">
                    <!-- Begin 5 columns container -->
                    <div class="ddHeader">
                        <div class="leftCorner">
                            <div class="rightCorner">
                                &nbsp;
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="leftShadow">
                        <div class="rightShadow">
                            <div class="ddContent clearfix">

                                        <div class="col_1_logo">
                                            <a href="/WisestKid/Home?fm=link_navigated" title="Campbell’s&reg; Condensed soup">
                                                <img width="65" height="27" alt="Campbell’s&reg; Condensed soup" src="~/media/OurBrands/Logos/campbells.ashx?mh=38&amp;mw=65"></a>
                                        </div>

                                        <div class="col_1_logo">
                                            <a id="plhheader_0_rptBrands_lnkBrand_0" title="Campbell&#39;s® Gravies" href="/Brands/Campbells%20Gravies?fm=link_navigated"><img src="/~/media/OurBrands/Logos/campbells_gravy.ashx?h=38&amp;mh=38&amp;mw=65&amp;w=57" alt="Campbells Gravy" width="57" height="38" /></a>
                                        </div>

                                        <div class="col_1_logo">
                                            <a id="plhheader_0_rptBrands_lnkBrand_1" title="Swanson® Broth and Stock" href="http://www.campbellskitchen.com/Swanson/Home.aspx?fm=theater"><img src="/~/media/OurBrands/Logos/SwansonFB_llogo.ashx?h=36&amp;mh=38&amp;mw=65&amp;w=65" alt="Swanson" width="65" height="36" /></a>
                                        </div>

                                        <div class="col_1_logo">
                                            <a id="plhheader_0_rptBrands_lnkBrand_2" title="Pace® Sauces" href="/Brands/Pace%20Sauces?fm=link_navigated"><img src="/~/media/OurBrands/Logos/pace.ashx?h=38&amp;mh=38&amp;mw=65&amp;w=60" alt="Pace" width="60" height="38" /></a>
                                        </div>

                                        <div class="col_1_logo">
                                            <a id="plhheader_0_rptBrands_lnkBrand_3" title="Prego® Sauce" href="/Brands/Prego%20Sauce?fm=link_navigated"><img src="/~/media/OurBrands/Logos/prego.ashx?h=25&amp;mh=38&amp;mw=65&amp;w=65" alt="Prego" width="65" height="25" /></a>
                                        </div>

                                        <div class="col_1_logo">
                                            <a id="plhheader_0_rptBrands_lnkBrand_4" title="Pepperidge Farm®" href="/Brands/Pepperidge%20Farm?fm=link_navigated"><img src="/~/media/OurBrands/Logos/pepperidge_farm.ashx?h=22&amp;mh=38&amp;mw=65&amp;w=65" alt="Pepperidge Farms" width="65" height="22" /></a>
                                        </div>

                                        <div class="col_1_logo">
                                            <a id="plhheader_0_rptBrands_lnkBrand_5" title="Soup Plus" href="/Brands/Soup%20Plus?fm=link_navigated"></a>
                                        </div>

                                <div class="col_3">
                                    <a href="/Brands?fm=link_navigated" title="See All Our Brands">
                                        See All Our Brands</a>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <!-- ddContent -->
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="ddFooter">
                        <div class="leftCorner">
                            <div class="rightCorner">
                                &nbsp;
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <!-- End 5 columns container -->
            </li>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get the text node with `a[@title]/text()`.

Means: all text nodes that are children of anchors/links having the attibute "title" while `a/@title/text()` means: find all anchors/links, then find attribute child nodes, then select the text node children *of these attribute nodes*. Since attributes haven't got any child nodes, the result is an empty set.

As mentioned in comments, there are images instead of text nodes inside the BRANDS links. Consider to retrieve the `alt` attributes of `<img>` tags instead.

After the discussion and edits I understand: You do want the title attrubutes and transform this to an array of values. Here's an example with GreaseMonkey

```
console.log
( GM_xpath({ path: "//a[contains(.,'BRAND')]/following-sibling::div//a/@title", all:true })
    .map(function(item){ return item.value;})
);
```

If you get a `NodeList` from your function that is not an array you can use `map()` as it would be a method of the iteratable list: `Array.prototype.map.call(list, function(){})`

Comment: This doesn't work. if I go to the above link and use $x("//a[contains(.,'BRAND')]/following-sibling::div//a/@title/text()") it returns me empty

Comment: $x("//a[contains(.,'BRAND')]/following-sibling::div//a[@title]/text()" doesn't work either...

Comment: I've edited the code to a little bit more complete code example.

Comment: Haven't tested. Can you provide a short test case for copy'n'paste?

Comment: Revised the question with example

Comment: I've testet the linked page in GreaseMonkey: `console.log(GM_xpath({ path: "//a[contains(.,'RECIPE')]/following-sibling::div//a[@title]/text()", all:true }));` result: `"[www.campbellskitchen.com-abd4baff-3055-496e-a7bc-febdd7a8f33b@scriptish]" Array [ #text "Best of the Season", #text "Quick & Easy", #text "Budget Friendly", #text "Family Favorites", #text "Comfort Classics", #text "Nutritious & Delicious", #text "Creative & Different", #text "Top 10 Collections", #text "Wisest Kid in the Whole World™", #text "New Latin Inspired Collection", 15 weitere… ]`

Comment: Please test the BRAND instead of RECIPE then you will see it breaks

Comment: Tested with BRAND: `"[www.campbellskitchen.com-abd4baff-3055-496e-a7bc-febdd7a8f33b@scriptish]" Array [ #text "
                                                ", #text "
                                        See All Our Brands" ]` That's correct, since other elements do not have text nodes, there are images inside.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/56233/discussion-between-peiti-peter-li-and-quasimodos-clone).

Comment: I'm sitting in the chat but cannot see any response.

Answer (score 0):

`$x` returns the selected DOM nodes, if you want to extract data from those nodes you'll have to do it in JavaScript as a second step, e.g.

```
$x(someXpath).map(function(n) { return n.nodeValue; });
```